# How can I make a psudo element the same width as its element

Tags: html, css

I just started learning about pseudo-elements in CSS, like `::before` and `::after`. I am trying to make an after element the same width as its parent. For example:

```
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

```
a::before{
content: "";
height: 20px;
width: ?
}
```

I want to put the width the same as the element. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%`? I 'd like to see more context.

Comment: When I put width: 100% it makes the element go all the way across the page.

Comment: I want the css to change the width of the ::before element based on what the parent is. edit: ex. if the width of the parent is 100px I want the ::before to  be 100px, but if the width is 1000px, I want the ::before to be 1000px

Comment: I just go it figured out. I never put the `position: relative;` on the a element. Thats all I needed to do

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the `a` element's position to `relative` and the pseudo-element's position to `absolute`.

This will make the pseudo-element "inherit" its original element's width, allowing you to set `width: 100%`.

Like this:

```css
a{
  position: relative;
}

a::after{
content: "";
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `<div>` to wrap the `<a>` and need to set the width of `<div>`, before you use `inherit`. Also use `position:relative` in the parent and `position:absolute` in the child:

```css
div::before{
 content: "Read this -";
 height: 20px;
 width:inherit;
 position:absolute;
 background-color: grey;
 right:100%;
 
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: yellow;left: 15em; position:relative; width:15em">
    <a href="#" >Read this this this this this</a>
</div>
```